# Angular factory function executing only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two modules **module-1** and **module-2** in my angular application.

In **module-1**, I have created a factory

```
angular.module('ui.campaign.manager').factory('validate',['the',function(the) {
return {
    validateOwner: function(scope) {
        console.log(scope.campaign);
        if(!scope.campaign.owner) {
          scope.view = true;
          scope.errormsg = "Error : Campaign owner is a mandatory field. Please select one from the dropdown menu.";
          return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

}]);

In module-2, there is a controller where I am calling this function on ng-click

```
var campaignApp = angular.module('module-2',[ 'module-1']);

campaignApp.controller('campaignDetailController', function($scope,    validate) {

    scope.submitCampaignPage = function(){
        validate.validateOwner($scope);
    }
});
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next" name="campdetailsnext" ng-click="submitCampaignPage()">
```

Now, the issue is for the first time when I am clicking on Next button **validateOwner** function is getting invoked properly while on subsequent clicks submitCampaignPage function is being called but validateOwner function is not getting invoked at all.

Is angular caching the results?

Comment: Any errors in console log? Please add your full module configuration where `scope.submitCampaingPage` is defined in.

Comment: No, there are no errors in console log

Comment: Please add the requested code. Does `console.log(scope.campaign);` work -> write an output?

Comment: No, it is working only for the first click.After that, it doesnot go into validateOwner function only.

Comment: I see you marked not right answer in your questions right now. Please dont forget to mark the right answer by clicking the "tick" near the answer vote buttons (its greyed out at the start).

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the function parameter as `$scope` not as `scope`.

Also, make sure to declare `scope.campaign` as object in controller or factory otherwise there is an exception raised trying to access property of undefined

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,validate){
$scope.campaign = {}
  $scope.submitCampaignPage = function(){
    console.log(validate.validateOwner($scope))
 }

}).factory('validate',function() {
  return {
      validateOwner: function(scope) { 
          if(!scope.campaign.owner) {
            scope.view = true;
            scope.errormsg = "Error : Campaign owner is a mandatory field. Please select one from the dropdown menu.";
            return false;
          }
          return true;
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next" name="campdetailsnext" ng-click="submitCampaignPage()">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, that is $scope only and $scope.campaign is also defined in controller, and for first time when I am calling validateOwner function it is printing scope.campaign value properly.

Answer (score 0):

did you try putting the controller and factory on the same module just to test? because I just tried with both controller and factory on the same module and it works just fine.